# AMP page with basic authentication

Tags: basic-authentication, amp-html

I have an AMP page which my client wants to test before we release it. We secure our client testing environment using basic authentication.

I'm using an AMP list with a JSON src attribute to template my list

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="720" layout="fixed-height" src="/amp/_data/mydata.json">
    <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-id">
        <div>
            <a href="{{url}}">{{linkText}}</a>
        </div>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

When I load this page in Chrome the server responds with a 401, which suggests that assets on the page aren't being loaded using the basic authentication credentials used for the AMP page.

Without specifying the username and password in the URL (eg. `http://user:password@my.staging.server...`) is there any way I can get additional requests to be made using the same basic authentication credentials as the AMP page?

Comment: Which basic authentication technique are you using for the AMP page?

Comment: @kul3r4 What do you mean by technique in this context? I'm using HTTP Basic authentication

Comment: You might want to check their tutorial - [Create a login-requiring AMP page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/login_requiring/login), this show how to implement authentication in an AMP page. Their is also an extension that is under active development [amp-access](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-access) that you might want to check. Hope this info helps.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using a relative URL for your JSON data?

It's my understanding that AMP generally discourages this because it won't be the correct link if the AMP page is delivered from AMP Cache.